# How to send an email on Plone?

Tags: email, plone

Please guide me how to send an email Plone. I have read the description on Plone website, but I couldn't understand about Postfix (https://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/config/mail.html), if anyone has any idea about that, that'd be great. How to send an email localhost? My knowledge of Python is really basic. 
I would like to be able to send an email without using SMTP.

Thank you!

Comment: It is recommended to post your question here, too: https://community.plone.org/ You can just add a link to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP is *the* very protocol for sending mails, so you can't do it without it.

You can however configure a Plone-site to use an existing mail-account and its SMTP-server for sending out mails through the site's UI. That's done in the mail-controlpanel, accessible via: `[SITE_URL]/mail-controlpanel`.

Once that is set, one can get pretty far with defining when to send who what content, by using Plone's content-rules and choosing "send-a-mail" as the action to be done after a certain event happened, like e.g. "A news-item was added, send it as a mail to group XY".

If you want to send mails to groups you need to use the add-on "collective.contentrules.mailtogroup".

It used to be capable to transfer a rich-body-text-field also, but that had been unintentionally deleted and was never restored, but one can use the older version before the deletion. A fork with a development-branch, lives here:
https://github.com/ida/collective.contentrules.mailtogroup/tree/forumail

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your network, you may be able to specify 'localhost' and port 25 as the SMTP server settings of your Plone site, in its Mail control panel.